# ReactJS: Finding the id of a specific request to use in a function that will dispatch an action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a React application and I am using Redux to store the state. I have the following code:

request.component.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './request.styles.scss';

class Request extends Component {

    handleClick = () => {
        this.props.removeRequest(this.props.request.id);
    }

    render() {
        const { requests } = this.props;
        const requestList = requests.map(request => {
            return (
                <div className="request-box" key={request.id}>
                    <div className="request-details">
                        <div>
                             <h1>Table {request.id}, {request.timestamp}</h1>
                             <h2>{request.description}</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div className="status-button">
                            <button type="button" className="request-button" onClick={this.handleClick}>{request.status}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div className="request-list">
                {requestList}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        requests: state.requests
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        removeRequest: (id) => { dispatch({type: 'REMOVE_REQUEST', id: id}) }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Request);
```

The above Request component is displayed in the following page:

requests.component.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Request from '../../components/request/request.component';

import './requests.styles.scss';


class RequestListPage extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="requests-page">
                <h1>Requests</h1>
                <div className="requests-container">
                    <Request />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default RequestListPage;
```

I have the following data as the initial state.

requests.data.js:

```
export default [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Completed"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Assistance Requested"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Assistance Requested"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Assistance Requested"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Assistance Requested"
        },
    ]
```

requests.reducer.js:

```
import INITIAL_STATE from './requests.data';

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    console.log(action);
    return state;
}
```

rootReducer.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import userReducer from './user/user.reducer';
import requestsReducer from './requests/requests.reducer'

export default combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
    requests: requestsReducer
})
```

In request.component.jsx, I have a function called removeRequest() which is called whenever the button in a Request component is clicked. Calling the removeRequest() function will dispatch the action 'REMOVE_REQUEST'. The removeRequest() takes the id of a request as a parameter.

However, since I have a list of requests, I am not sure how to obtain the id of a specific request that is clicked.

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: You need to change `onClick` as this : 
`onClick={(request.id) => this.handleClick(request.id)}`

You are mapping over requests, so you just need to pass request.id as params in handler

Let me know if this works, I'll post this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your button:

```
<button type="button" className="request-button" 
onClick={this.handleClick}>{request.status}</button>
```

You can pass the id:

```
<button type="button" className="request-button" 
onClick={() => this.handleClick(request.id)}>{request.status}</button>
```

You'll need to change your handleClick to accept a parameter:

```
handleClick = (id) => {
    this.props.removeRequest(id);
}
```